# How can I stop the auto-renewal of app after the expiring of free trial?

Tags: credit-card

İ  forgot cancelling  free trial and it expired then I removed the subscription on Google play. But the app  is still trying to withdraw money.

Comment: does google's own site [not answer this](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644008?hl=en)?

Answer (score 2):

99% of the time when you sign up for a free trial you have to accept the terms of the trial, which usually includes something like: "Cancel for free before 10/23/2020. I understand that if I do not cancel before 10/23/2020 then I will be billed monthly beginning on 10/24/2020."

So no, if you're past the free trial phase then they can bill you and you owe the money. The best way to avoid this is to set reminders on your phone or someplace else so you remember to cancel before the end date.

Comment: Or just cancel immediately after signing up.  Most free trials that I'm familiar with will keep working through the trial period even if you cancel ten minutes after signing up.  If you decide that you actually like the service and want to pay for it, you can sign up again "for real" when the trial period ends.

Comment: fortunately it  stopped withdrawing money.